# From a custom module. How can I get the typed value from a textfield and put it in a variable?

Tags: 7, forms

In a drupal page, I have a form where I need to read a text field value of an element, via javascript, when it is typed by the user, just after the input field lost the focus and before submit is done, I need to save it in a variable.

Answer (score 2):

All entered values are in the `$form_state` array on submit. It is up to you to process that data and store it in a variable.

For example...

```
function mymodule_myform_submit($form, $form_state) {
  $text = $form_state['values']['myfield'];
  variable_set('mymodule_var', $text);
}
```

Then wherever else in the site you want to show it...

```
$myvar = variable_get('mymodule_var', '');
```

Of course, be sure to validate your input in the validate handler and anything else you want to process and save. This is pretty much the most basic approach in 7 to collect and store variables (especially not knowing the rest of your setup).

Comment: use [variable_del('mymodule_var');](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_del/7.x) if you need to get rid off it after.

Comment: I need to get the value inmediatly after the user type it, just after the input field lost the focus, and before submit button is clicked. I need to get the value via javascript to make some actions with this value.